# Getting NSLocalizedDescription Correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to get error code with MKStoreKit but I cannot reach the localized description I want. Here is the object that I need to reach its description:

[image]

I am trying to get "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" by:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[[note object] userInfo] localizedDescription]);
```

but I get an error. I am wondering how to solve this.

Comment: It should be just `object.localizedDescription` where object is of type `NSError`

Comment: Ah thats correct. Thanks very much!